# How to match Transformer output Impedance for Ultrasonic Cleaning Transducer

Tags: transformer, impedance, impedance-matching, ultrasound, transducer

I have a transformer outputting the 240VAC 40kHz. The Transducer is 50W, 4100pF, 10-20 Ohm at resonance, ~40kHz resonance)

The Secondary of the transformer is 12mH.

I am trying to match the impedance of the output to ensure the former load is right and not overloading the switching gear on the primary side.
What would be a good starting point for an L/C or R/L/C to match the impedance to the driver?

Thanks in advance!